# Joomla - Determining whether logged-in user is an Admin

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, user-accounts, administrator

I am having tons of fun working on a big project that was, for reasons hard to justify, based on Joomla! (which I don't mean to criticise, Joomla! is great, just not for the task I am faced with currently) and when I googled for a way of determining whether the currently logged-in user is an Admin, I found a post that quite boldly recommends using the following code:

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if($user->usertype == "Super Administrator" || $user->usertype == "Administrator"){ ... }
```

To me, this looks like a rather strange way of checking for Admin users. I would appreciate a `$user->isAdmin()` method to do this rather than a couple of hard-coded strings.

I fail to find a more elegant solution to checking for admin users within the Joomla! framework. Can anyone help?

Comment: $user =& JFactory::getUser(); is pretty elegant. You can test all nine types of user (including the four kinds of Admin) in two lines of code. Plus, in most cases $user is already called and you just have to put in your second line of code. Sad to see Joomla move away from this in 1.6 +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, as the **Access levels are [hard coded](http://help.joomla.org/content/view/25/162/)** into the database in Joomla! 1.5, the only way this string comparison could fail is when someone deliberately hacked new groups into it. Strings can be changed in the .ini-Files (so that non-english installations still use the english words in the database - this is not true for other tables like the names of plugins or components.)

You could **get the group id** via `JFactory::getACL()`, and then `$acl->getGroupsByUser($userid, false)` (see [docs](http://docs.joomla.org/JAccess/getGroupsByUser)), but assuming that a greater id means greater privileges as well, seems a bit hacky, too (though true for a standard installation).

Other than that, you could **take over a Joomla! capability**: define more explicitly, what a "admin user" is: someone who can install new software? who can change the system's configuration? Just make a reasonable assumption, something related to what you want him to do as a admin user, use it in a `authorize()`-Call (see [docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_current_user_object#Privileges)), and maybe document it in your interface.

The only clean solution (that I know of) would be to **define new entries for the ACL-authorize-lookuptable** (currently implemented in php only, not SQL). This is the only way to ensure that it will be Joomla! 1.6-proof, where custom user groups will be possible (and so the admin user can choose to give this authorization to a user group or not). For example:

```
$acl =& JFactory::getACL();
$acl->addACL('{com_nameOfExtension}', '{action}', 'users', 'super administrator');
$acl->addACL('{com_nameOfExtension}', '{action}', 'users', 'administrator');
```

And there we have them again, hard-coded groupnames. Well.

Comment: as far as I know, JFactory::getACL() returns a JAuthorization instance, which does not have a getGroupsByUser() method... http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/User/JAuthorization.html

Answer (score 2):

Peter,

I concur on the joomla sentiments, we use .net/php here as well and have a few projects that were started on joomla for some unknown reason !!

amnyway, another finer grained approach may be to examine the actual rights that the user has, rather than them being suoper admin etc. you can get to this info along the following lines:

```
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();

    if ($user->authorize('com_content', 'edit', 'content', 'all')) {
            echo "<p>You may edit all content.</p>";
    } else {
            echo "<p>You may not edit all content.</p>";
    }

    if ($user->authorize('com_content', 'publish', 'content', 'own')) {
            echo "<p>You may publish your own content.</p>";
    } else {
            echo "<p>You may not publish your own content.</p>";
    }
```

i know it's still hardcoded but at least it's user specific, rather than priviledge specific. this approach does however allow you to target specific 'component' related priviledges, so might be useful for you.

I'll track the replies to see if there's a 'proper' answer as it definately is an omission.

jim

Comment: cheers, jim. I was just looking at the authorize() function but it's not quite what I need. I often need to check specifically for the one and only super administrator and then filter or not filter some of entries in the back-end administration panel. I often need to check whether the logged in user is 'Super Admin' or 'Admin'.

Comment: peter - in that case, the search continues :)

Comment: I guess I'll have to offer a bounty :-) but only a very small one

Answer (score 0):

The following could be a hack on Joomla. I tried it and got worked.

Take the case of sessions

```
$_SESSION[__default][user]->usertype;
```

This will give the type of user logged in you can use this in any conditional statements

Comment: sorry but I know how to get to the current user's usertype attribute, as you could have noticed in the question itself:

$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if($user->usertype == ...

But this still only returns a string representation of the user type and then I have to do string comparisons...

Answer (score 0):

You can check 'assigned user groups' of the logged in user using getUser() function.

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();

$assigned_usergroups = $user->groups; // Array of assigned User Group

    if (in_array(8, $assigned_usergroups)) {
        echo "Super Admin";
    }

    else if (in_array(7, $assigned_usergroups)) {
        echo "Admin";
    }

    else {    
        echo "Other"; //Any of Guest/Public/Others
    }
```

You can see the following snapshot of the Joomla's predefined IDs for each User Group in the Database:

[Snapshot here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz1O4rE3GY0vTER4b000VEZEMDQ/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score -1):

If ur joomla administrator username is `admin` then u can use below code aspeter described before

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if($user->usertype == "Super Administrator" && $user->username == "admin")
{
  //... do what ever
}
```

Comment: Oh, no, no, no. Don't like the looks of this. The moment someone configures the admin to use a different name, the whole application will break in various places. Plus, it's recommended to change the default admin user name to something else for the production system.

Comment: sorry Peter, i m also newbie, i just suggest, thanks to updating my knowledge

Comment: Better still, use the admin user only to create another Super admin user and deactivate the first one. That's like renaming the administrator-Folder (which is less easier to do) to keep the 90% of easy attacks out.

Comment: @giraff, even better, yep! :-) btw, JustLearn, I see you're just learning, no worries. The down-vote is not from me, I believe even your contribution contributes to the topic., so I'll even that out by an up-vote